# how do i obtain soap request and response from web service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I want to obtain a soap request in xml format of a web service (not wcf). I tried the msdn example of soap trace extension.

It works, but I don't want to log it , I want to obtain it in a string and display in a web browser control, in winforms.

Comment: How are you trying to access your WS? via the browser? i.e http://localhost/Service.asmx ?

Comment: [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Even though your service is ASMX, you can use a Service Reference so that the client is using WCF. One of the benefits of that is that you can use WCF features like [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) and [message inspection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).

I know you say that you don't want to use tracing, but using tracing (in particular, message logging) with a custom trace listener may be a simple solution. If not, then message inspection should take care of anything you might need.